# thrift installation error

Tags: cassandra, thrift

i am trying more than 2 hours to install thrift with cassandra but it is not even configured..when i am configure using command ./configure it show the error as:
configure: error: Cannot find php-config. Please use --with-php-config=PATH
configure: error: ./configure failed for lib/php/src/ext/thrift_protocol

i cant fix this. can any one help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure to install php-dev. it happened with me last weekend. good luck.

Comment: if you use ubuntu you should be able to install php-dev in application manager.  do you know how to install software in ubuntu?

Comment: hello sir i am using fedora and i installed php-devl. even after installing the thrift not working. what can i do?if you are free please give some idea...

Comment: Ohh.  I use ubuntu and when I did that it works.  Are you getting same message???

Answer (score 1):

Same thing with Ubuntu Lucid. Installed php5-dev via apt-get and it works.

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS 5.6, you're looking for php5-devel or php53-devel

installed by "yum install ...."