# Problems installing Thrift

Tags: php, ubuntu, apc, thrift, ubuntu-server

Here is a screen shot of the error I am getting:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20599297/Screen%20shot%202011-05-25%20at%203.41.36%20PM.png

I really don't know what the problem is.

I have PHP installed with APC maybe thats the problem...

I am running on Ubuntu Server.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Also a copy of the command you executed would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple. Install package python-dev. I think you also need to install python before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your libtool library is messed up. You should try removing libtool from apt-get and compiling it manually.

> I got the same error under debian lenny.
>
> The problem is the libool 1.5.26 installed via apt which raises the errors.
>
> To build thrift download the libtool 1.5.24 source from
>
> ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/libtool-1.5.24.tar.gz
>
> build it (./configure;make) and copy the libtool executable to the thrift source directory after you > ran ./configure.
>
> Now 'make' should work and generate the thrift executable.

SRC: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9435157&postcount=4

Comment: New problem: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20599297/Screen%20shot%202011-05-26%20at%204.51.59%20PM.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721385/error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1

Comment: I re-installed Python and I was able to "make" thrift... But now when I do "make install" I get this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20599297/Screen%20shot%202011-05-26%20at%206.57.42%20PM.png

Comment: I tried to re-start from the beginning... So I did: ./bootstrap.sh

But since it's not where they say it is I had to find it. It was in: ./contrib/fb303/bootstrap.sh

Here is the error I get:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20599297/Screen%20shot%202011-05-26%20at%207.22.02%20PM.png

Comment: It still looks like your libtool is messed up. Also did you use "make distclean"

Comment: I just loaded a EC2 server on AWS Amazon to try it out. And I still get the same error message. Here are my configs: http://ec2-50-19-147-202.compute-1.amazonaws.com/phpinfo.php I also installed: libboost-dev libboost-test1.40-dev libevent-dev automake libtool flex bison pkg-config g++ I really don't know anymore what to do. I cannot believe I am the only one who ran into this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077233/thrift-installation-error What everyone is saying is that you need php5-dev installed for it to run

Comment: But I did install it. If I did not then how come this page works: http://ec2-50-19-147-202.compute-1.amazonaws.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: That page works because you have php installed, php-dev is another package that adds development tools that work with php

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php-dev

Comment: you have the package "php5-dev"

Comment: Yes I have php5-dev installed.

Comment: Here are the errors I am getting:
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/protocol/fastbinary.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/protocol/fastbinary.o
src/protocol/fastbinary.c:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make[3]: *** [all-local] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/thrift-0.6.0/lib/py'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/thrift-0.6.0/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/thrift-0.6.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2